# How to create Java List of Type E extends Comparable<? super E>

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the Quicksort method written in java on Rosettacode.org.

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Java

However, I do not know how to add elements to a LinkedList of type E in order to use the method.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void main(String[] args) {

        List<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();

        list.add(1);
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
QuickSort.java:12: error: no suitable method found for add(int)         list.add(1);
            ^
    method List.add(int,E) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method List.add(E) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to E by method invocation conversion)
    method Collection.add(E) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to E by method invocation conversion)   where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<? super E> declared in method <E>main(String[]) 1 error make: *** [c] Error 1
```

Comment: This code isn't meant to reside inside your `main` method. You're switching between generic and non-generic types which, as you can see, doesn't work (how would the compiler know if `1` is compatible with `E`?). I'm not at all sure what you're trying to achieve though, the article you linked to already has the quicksort code implemented so why are you trying to rewrite it?

Comment: @JonK I am not trying to rewrite it, I am trying to implement it.

Comment: But it already has been implemented - the quickSort method that you're linking to **is** the implementation. By "implement" do you mean "*use*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of issues here.

First, why are you declaring your main method as `static<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`.

Secondly, you have bounded the `list` to a generic type `E` but have not specified what `E` is. Thus, to add an `int` into a list that has no **specific** type will cause a conversion issue by the compiler.
Also, an `int` is a primitive type, it doesn't follow, even when it's autoboxed to `java.lang.Integer`, it doesn't satisfy the constraint since `E` is not specific/specified.

I hope this helps.

---

Update:

Based on the link you provided, this is how you will to use the `quickSort()` function.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(); //If using JDK 7 and higher.
```

OR

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //If using JDK 6 and JDK 5.
```

Now...

```
//Add all your items in the list.
intList.add(1);
intList.add(50);
intList.add(10);
intList.add(8);
intList.add(-24);
//...etc.

//Sort,
intList = quickSort(intList);
```

Since `E` is bounded to an object that is `Comparable`, it will accept any list that conforms to that bounding.

Comment: Thank you. So my question then is, how do I specify E as an Integer?

Comment: See my updated post, the function is bounded by a generic type `E` such that the compiler can determine the specific type. In this case, it case see an `Integer` as a specific class type and binds `E` to `java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add Integer ,You should change

```
 List<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
```

to

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

The reason why you are getting error is due to the fact that when you declared `List<E>` then all you can add into list is Element of type `E` and Integer is not `E`

Comment: There is a `List.add(int index, E element)` method in the `java.util.List` interface.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi where i mentioned that there is no method like this

Comment: Oops. sorry, fixing the problem.